# USB modem auto connect in Windows 10 on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: c#, modem, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I would like to use a Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10 for IoT in an m2m solution where it is important that the Raspberry always is online.

On Linux I would have used Sakis3g and UMTSKeeper, but for this project my plan is to give Windows 10 a try. The software that should run on the device I plan to write using .NET and C#.

I'm trying to be open-minded about the solution, maybe it's a tool to install, some library I can call from my own software, or just some code that let me open and keep the connection myself.

It would be great if the solution is so generic that there were no need to install drivers for each modem to use, since I don't know on beforehand what modems that will be used.

Comment: A tool or library recommendation would be off-topic, as would drivers.

Comment: @MSalters Off-topic, you say? Maybe you can suggest a forum (Stack Exchange or other) where my question would be on-topic?

Comment: Well, there's a Software Recommendations SE. Still in beta, I think, but open.

Comment: About drivers, as I wrote in the question, I'm not asking about drivers, I'm asking about code that makes drivers unnecessary.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: No, not yet. This is a low priority side-project, so it might take a while before I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Putty tools work great with Windows 10 and Raspberry PI.

Comment: How do I use Putty to make the Raspberry to connect to Internet using an USB modem on startup, and to stay online? The Raspberry is not connected to any other network, this is the reason why the modem needs to be connected all the time.

Comment: idk about Raspberry modems, but I know from windows you can ssh into Raspberry using Putty or PLink (and you can pass in parameters when you call either Putty program) or you can send across single-line commands (like to transfer files) using pscp, another exe from the Putty library. Try the Putty FAQ...  http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Raspberry pie has built in wifi. If you set it to connect to a local router you can use that as your pipe to surf the internet.

Comment: You're not reading the question. I would like the raspberry to automatically connect using a MODEM for an m2m solution. Wifi and surfing has nothing to do with this. If you do not now anything about how to use a modem together with the raspberry, as you stated earlier, then you cannot possibly now the answer for my question.

Comment: I only provided the solution I use to pull information from the Raspberry pie device and to connect to Raspberry from my Windows applications.

However, since putty tools are also compatible with Linux there may very well be a solution to use from the Raspberry interface to run your modem, but I can't answer that portion of your question.

Comment: Doesn't it seem strange that a person can answer questions here, before they can comment on even open questions? If you feel my answer is not helpful, then I will be happy to remove it.

Comment: I'm not using Linux. I'm running Windows 10 on the raspberry!

I have no keyboard and no screen connected to the raspberry, so I would like it to automatically connect to Internet so that other software running on it can reports it's data to a server.

Comment: Wow! I hadn't thought of running 10 on a Raspberry, and I wouldn't. I am convinced that the Linux on the Raspberry is the best platform at this time. You will definitely have the jump on others attempting to do the same.